# What is _/_ in a conan package?

Tags: conan

Is `openssl/1.1.1d@_/_` the same as `openssl/1.1.1d`? I'm confused by those different suffixes like `_/_`, `conan/stable`, `bincrafters/stable`, are they eventually replaced by `openssl/1.1.1d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Since Conan 1.18, the namespace (user/channel) has become optional. Thus, the correct reference for the official OpenSSL package now is `openssl/<version>` e.g.

```
conan install -r conan-center openssl/1.1.1d@
```

The `@` is required to identify that you are using using name/version format. It's a compatibility feature.

However, the package folder path uses same format yet, e.g.

```
/home/user/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2o/conan/stable/package/6af9cc7cb931c5ad94
```

Now, without the namespace, both user and channel has been replaced by the placeholder `_/_`:

```
/home/user/.conan/data/openssl/1.0.2o/_/_/package/6af9cc7cb931c5ad94
```

Note that you don't need to touch this, you only need to invoke the reference by putting a `@` as terminator.

Comment: Are `_/_` and `conan/stable` the same thing? Is there any document taking detailed information about different channels? I was looking for x86 binaries, the conan-center doesn't provide them anymore.

Comment: No. Again, `_/_` are placeholders for user and channel, thus they are different packages.